# How do I create and combine column matrices from lists

Tags: matrix

I need to input the following list of values for x and y , each as a column matrix (7-row, 1-column). Then, combine the two into a 2 x 7 column matrix. I'm new to Mathematica. Please help. How do I do this? Thank you.

```
x = 1.13 | 2.56 | 3.42 | 4.75 | 5.39 | 6.84 | 7.25
y = 3.83 | 4.15 | 3.79 | 1.78 | 0.23 | −0.76 |  −1.25
```

Comment: You could just input them as a list (e.g. `x = {1.13, ..., 7.25}`) and `Transpose` `x` and `y` afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica uses the list for almost everything.  You can think of a `list` as a row for now for purposes of making matrices.

So when you write `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,2}}` then this is a matrix of two rows.

To convert this to matrix of 2 columns, you transpose it. So by transposing at the end, you are telling Mathematica, these rows are really columns.

```
Transpose[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So always start with the idea that lists are rows. To do what you want for your data:

```
x = {1.13, 2.56, 3.42, 4.75, 5.39, 6.84, 7.25}
y = {3.83, 4.15, 3.79, 1.78, 0.23, -0.76, -1.25}
mat = {x, y}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is matrix with 2 rows. But you want these to be columns, not rows. Then do an extra step

```
mat = Transpose[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You'll see this alot in Mathematica when working with matrices. You construct the matrix as rows, since that is the natural way for Mathematica, then add a transpose at the end.  This is a little different from Matlab.

Comment: Thank you Nasser. I get it now from your explanation.

Comment: (+1) and a minor comment for completeness: `Thread@mat` is equivalent to the `Transpose@mat`